# Ubuntu 20.04 errors after suspend: ACPI Error and DRM error

Tags: 20.04, suspend, acpi, xps, drm

I am running Ubuntu `20.04` on an `XPS15`. And everytime I suspend and then come back from it, I get the following messages on the screen before the system actually starts:

```
ACPI Error: Thread 3824... cannot release Mutex [ECMX] acquired by thread 2383... (20200528/exmutex-378)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) 20200528/psparse-529)
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] **ERROR** failed to enable link training
```